# Wordpress Plugin Execution Order

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Is there any method available to check my plugin is loaded after another plugin is loaded in Wordpress? The plugin I develop is in conflict with another plugin. So I want to make sure that my plugin is loaded only after the conflicting plugin is loaded. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In `wp-settings.php`, WordPress first checks for any `must-use plugins` (plugins in the optional mu-plugins folder) and loads those.

Then, if you're running a multisite installation, it checks for plugins that are `network-activated` and loads those.

Then it checks for all other active plugins by looking at the active_plugins entry of the wp_options database table, and loops through those. The plugins will be listed alphabetically.

Here's the order WordPress loads pretty much everything: http://codex.wordpress.org/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request

The thing is, it usually doesn't matter what order each individual plugin is loaded in, because properly-written plugins will use WordPress hooks, which let you plug in functionality into specific points later in the WordPress startup. (Properly-written plugins will also prefix their functions and classes so that there aren't any conflicts.)

More info on plugin API: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/

Comment: It's insulting to say well written plugins use hooks, as if the developer is doing terrible job. What about if you want to change an admin_menu_page of another plugin that doesn't offer you any hooks you can attach to ? Can you please show how can you make a well-written plugin in this case ? Thank you